# Changing the character string "20170804" to a date

Tags: r, date

I tried the `lubridate` package with `mdy` function and the `as.Date` function with the `format` argument

```
datechar2 <-"11/11/17"  # Nov 11, 2017
datechar3 <-"9-12-2017"  # Sep 12, 2017
datechar4 <-"April 13, 2017"
datechar5 <-"20170804"
```

In 2 and 3 with the `lubridate` function I am able to convert it to date type but i want to try with `as.Date` function but it is showing `NA`
In 4, I am not able to get the desired format with the `lubridate` package `mdy` function or with the `as.Date` function.

Comment: Use `anytime::anytime()` http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html

Comment: the function `mdy` from lubridate solves #3 and `ymd` or `ydm` solves #4 but it depends if you are on the american or european date system

Comment: @markus, I think `anytime::anydate()` is more appropriate ...

Comment: i want to use as.Date function in all of these.

Comment: i am able to do with lubridate

Comment: i want to make efforts in converting the dates into date type with as. Date function ,if possible

Answer (score 1):

See `?strptime` for details on format strings.  Note that `%b` and `%B` are locale-dependent ...

```
as.Date(datechar2, "%m/%d/%y")
as.Date(datechar3, "%m-%d-%Y")
as.Date(datechar4, "%B %d, %Y")
as.Date(datechar5, "%Y%m%d")
```

The last example "20170804" is slightly ambiguous (could be August 4 or April 8 ...)

Comment: i understand but how to convert it that is the real one

Comment: As far as I can tell my answer solves your problem. If it doesn't, please clarify what you want by commenting or editing your question ...